# Question about Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

[image]

Could someone please explain how they got from the first step to the next? I have no idea how the second step follows...

Comment: I worked through it myself but I'm not getting their answer either.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for working through it! Do you get any kind of clean answer at all?

Comment: It's the Discrete-Time Fourier transform of an impulse train, which is itself an impulse train. You get the desired result by representing the impulse train in the time domain by its Fourier series, which - as a sum of complex exponentials - will transform to a sum of Dirac deltas in the frequency domain.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146272/dtft-of-impulse-train-is-equal-to-0-through-my-equation/1146403#1146403) has all the details.